# Rspec: object isn't receiving method call from class method test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My test `"should call #logout_all"` is failing with

```
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments
```

but when I call `User.verify_from_token` directly in the `rails console`, I can see that `#logout_all` is being called (I added a `puts` statement to `#logout_all`)

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
    describe ".verify_from_token" do
      let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user, verified: false)}

      it "should return the user if found" do
        token = user.to_valid_token
        expect(User.verify_from_token token).to eq(user)
      end

      it "should verify the user" do
        token = user.to_valid_token
        User.verify_from_token token
        expect(user.reload.verified).to eq(true)
      end

      it "should call #logout_all" do
        token = user.to_valid_token
        expect(user).to receive(:logout_all)
        User.verify_from_token token
      end
    end
end


class User < ApplicationRecord

...

  def self.verify_from_token token
    user = from_token token
    if user
      user.update_attribute(:verified, true)
      user.logout_all
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

...
  def logout_all
    update_attribute(:token_timestamp, Time.now)
  end
end
```

If I rework the test slightly, it works fine.

```
 it "should call #logout_all" do
    token = user.to_valid_token
    t1 = user.token_timestamp
    User.verify_from_token token
    expect(t1 < user.reload.token_timestamp).to eq(true)
  end
```

Comment: Order for your `expect` and `User.verify_from_token token` is wrong. Right now you expect to receive a call first and only then call the method which calls the method you are expecting

Comment: No, the implementation is correct. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/expecting-messages

Comment: FWIW I prefer the second version of the test anyway, as you are testing the behaviour rather than the implementation. However, I don't see why the original version is failing; perhaps you've got some funny code in a `before` block or in the `spec_helper.rb`? Perhaps the `User#from_token` method isn't actually returning the user object? I'd need to dive in and debug it a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set expectation on one user, but method call happens on **another** user. This one.

```
user = from_token token
```

You didn't show implementation of `from_token`, but I'm willing to bet that it loads user from database. Now, there may be only one user in the database and, logically, these two variables represent the same entity. But physically, they're still two different objects in memory. So, naturally, the expectation is not met.

Comment: But since `token = user.to_valid_token`, I would expect this to work... In theory.... It all depends on the actual implementations of `User#to_valid_token` and `User#from_token`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Good catch.  `User.verify_from_token` decodes the JWT, pulls out the id, and returns the user with `User.find(id)`.  Then it calls `#logout_all` on that user.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
it "should call #logout_all" do
  token = user.to_valid_token
  allow(User).to receive(:from_token).once.with(token).and_return(user)
  expect(user).to receive(:logout_all)
  User.verify_from_token token
end
```

Like it was said before, the method is called on a new User instance, not the one you set te expectation. You have to stub the "from_token" class method to return the same object you are expecting messages on, not another instance with the same id from the database.

Comment: This is actually a very nice solution! I like that it tests whether `#logout_all` was called rather than testing the *behavior* of `#logout_all`(which should be tested elsewhere).